# LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Boolean Contains(Int32)' method

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

The below exception flown

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Boolean
>   Contains(Int32)' method,      and this method cannot be translated
>   into a store expression.

while trying to execute the below query

```
List<int> studentIDs = Common.getFilterStudents();
var query = from a in studentTable
            where studentIDs.Contains(a.StudentID)
            select a;
```

How can I filter the query using the studentIDs list?

Comment: Please see my edited code, I've modified the source of studentIDs

Comment: Which version of Entity Framework do you use?

Comment: Are you completely sure, that `studentIDs` has type `List<int>`?

Comment: @user2191496 is it possible to upgrade to EF4 or EF5?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not possible to use `Contains` in your EF version, because support for `Contains` was added in EF 4. Either upgrade your EF version (then your code will work without any problems), or use something like [manual expression building](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/095745fe-dcf0-4142-b684-b7e4a1ab59f0/where-in-clause):

```
var query = context.studentTable.Where(
    BuildContainsExpression<Student, int>(s => s.StudentID, studentIDs));
```

Comment: It'll be useful to have a way to bookmark answers that you want to go back to.