# Binding ArrayList to Repeater control using Entity Model

Tags: c#, asp.net, arraylist, session-variables, repeater

I am creating a shopping cart. Users would go to individual pages of products and click "add to cart" button. When that button is clicked, the ProductId is stored in an array list in Session["Cart"]. When they go to Cart.aspx, the repeater will display all the items in the array list. I am not sure how to use the array list with an Entity Model properly.

Here is what I have so far for the **code-behind**:

```html
if (Session["Cart"] != null)
        {
            using (ProjectEntities myEntities = new ProjectEntities())
            {
                ArrayList alProduct = new ArrayList();
                alProduct = (ArrayList)Session["Cart"];

                var product = (from p in myEntities.Products
                               where p.ProductId == Convert.ToInt32(alProduct)
                               select new { p.ProductName });

                Repeater1.DataSource = product.ToList();
                Repeater1.DataBind();
            }
        }
```

Here is the **markup** for Cart.aspx:

```html
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">
    <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblProductName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ProductName") %>'></asp:Label>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: Can you try this   var product = (from p in myEntities.Products
                               where p.ProductId == Convert.ToInt32(alProduct)
                               select new { p.ProductName }).ToList();

                Repeater1.DataSource = product;
                Repeater1.DataBind();

Comment: I tried that but it didn't work. It gave me this error message "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32 ToInt32(System.Object)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression." @Francis Saul

Comment: try to create a new arrayList and bind that new arraylist as datasource for the repeater.
     ArrayList productList = new ArrayList(product.ToList());

Comment: Why are you using an `ArrayList`? They're so 10 years ago. Why not use `List<T>`?

Comment: That was what I learned in class but I'll look into the List<T> @Enigmativity

Comment: @Enigmativity what's the difference of ArrayList and List<T>? Care to share your knowledge? thanks

Comment: @FrancisSaul - An `ArrayList` is not strongly-typed. You can add any type of object and you must cast when accessing items. There is always the danger of getting illegal casts. A `List<T>` is strongly-typed and avoids all of these issues. It's just much easier to write correct programs with `List<T>`.

Answer (score 0):

First problem with your code is here: `p.ProductId == Convert.ToInt32(alProduct)`. Since `alProduct` is an ArrayList it will never convert into an `integer` and will throw a run time exception. Change your query like this and use `Contains`:-

```
var product = (from p in myEntities.Products
               where alProduct.Contains(p.ProductId)
               select p.ProductName).ToList();
```

Since you are selecting just one item i.e. `ProductName` there is no need to project an anonymous type.

Also, there is no need to instantiate the ArrayList before assigning the value from session, although you should check for null before running the `product` query. I would suggest you to use a generic version of ArrayList i.e. `List<int>` instead of ArrayList.

Comment: I'm using ArrayList because I just learn this from class but i will look into the other alternatives. I type that above but it says something is wrong with the last line "Repeater1.DataBind();" and it gives this error message: "Data binding directly to a store query (DbSet, DbQuery, DbSqlQuery, DbRawSqlQuery) is not supported." @Rahul Singh

Comment: @RonT - Okay I forgot you are using entity framework, you can apply `ToList()` at the end to convert that to List<T>. Check my update.

Comment: I'm still using the ArrayList, would it affect it if I'm still using that since I'm not too sure how to use List<T> yet. I typed in your updated solution, and this time the error is in "var product = (from p in myEntities.Products" with the error message: "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Boolean Contains(System.Object)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression." @Rahul Singh

Comment: @RonT - Okay that means you are using entity framework version < 4. Any cance you can update the version? otherwise you will have to do it using manual expression as specified in this answer - http://stackoverflow.com/a/17940510/1529657

Comment: Oh really? I believe I am using EF version 6, it also says in my web.config @Rahul Singh

Comment: @RonT - Nope I don't think so, check this answer on how to check the version - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3377821/entity-framework-how-can-i-tell-what-version-i-am-using

Comment: I see, the System.Data.Entity.Design, does say Version=4.0.0.0. I'm going to figure out how to update the version. Thanks for all the help this far @Rahul Singh

Comment: @RonT - So were you able to figure out what was the issue?

Comment: Not yet, I will have to ask my professor tomorrow to see @Rahul Singh I tried to manually type it with the alternative method but I couldn't type "BuildContainsExpression"